# How to record username in Firebase analytics?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, event-log

How to record the user data e.g. USERNAME in log events for a Unity based ap using Firebase analytics?

Ex:

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.LogEvent("user_name", "abc");
```

Answer (score 1):

User IDs are not events - they are [user properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/properties).  You should [set a user property](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/properties#set_user_properties) for the current user with their ID, and that will get associated with all subsequent events for that user:

```
Firebase.Analytics.FirebaseAnalytics.SetUserProperty("user_name", "abc");
```

Comment: thnaks, we will test this out.